# Crystal reports export crashes C#

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, export, report

i have some problems in exporting crystal reports to pdf. My program crashes at the load of teleneUdaje.rpt and i am shure it is the right name.

if (txtpath.Text == "") throw new Exception("Prosím zvoľte cieľovú adresu");

```
    DataSet dt = new DataSet();

    string x = nastavenia.adresa_servera();
    string y = nastavenia.nazov_databazy();
    string z = nastavenia.ponechat_udaje();
    string a = nastavenia.sql_meno();
    string b = nastavenia.sql_heslo();

    SqlConnection databaza = new SqlConnection();
    databaza.ConnectionString = "Data Source=" + x + ";Initial Catalog=" + y + ";Persist Security Info=" + z + ";User ID=" + a + "; password=" + b + "";
    da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblTepelneUdaje", databaza);
    dt.Clear();
    da.Fill(dt);


    System.IO.FileInfo info = new System.IO.FileInfo(txtpath.Text.Trim());
    string type = info.Extension;

    CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType tp = CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.Excel;

    switch (type)
    {
        case ".pdf":
            tp = CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat;
            break;
        case ".doc":
            tp = CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.WordForWindows; break;
        case ".rtf":
            tp = CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.RichText; break;
        case ".xls":
            tp = CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.Excel; break;
        default: MessageBox.Show("Invalid File type you entered"); break;
    }

    ReportDocument doc = new ReportDocument();
    doc.Load("TeleneUdaje.rpt");
    doc.SetDataSource(dt);
    doc.ExportToDisk(tp, txtpath.Text);
    MessageBox.Show("Zostava bola úspešne exportovaná");
```

Please help.

** Edited

It throws Crystal Reports exception that the load of report failed. The File is OK because, within the program i can show reports with report viewer tool.

Comment: Crashes how? Does it throw an exception? Write anything to disk?

Comment: @AdamV it throws crystal report exception Report loading failed

Comment: It sounds like there's an issue with that report then. I don't have any experience with Crystal Reports, but I'd try opening it manually and see whether you see any errors in the file.

Comment: @AdamV the file is OK, i updated the code

Comment: The [crystal-reports] tag is one of the worst tags at SO.  The top answerer only gets 0.6 votes on average.  There is nobody from the company that owns it helping out.  Dismal stuff, ditch tools that *everybody* hates, you've got only one life to live.  Private rant from a victim of version 4 btw.

Comment: i found the problem. Ine the expression doc.Load("TeleneUdaje.rpt"); i  need to put the whole path like this doc.Load("C:\\TeleneUdaje.rpt");

Comment: @Michal: write up your solution below and choose it as the correct answer. That will help others who have the same problem as you and don't notice your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the correct answer to my question. 
the expression

```
doc.Load("TeleneUdaje.rpt")
```

is wrong because it needs the full path to the .rpt file like this:

```
doc.Load("C:\\report.rpt");
```

thx for comments guys